# Modify Joomla Tags Result Page

Tags: php, joomla

I want to show my article intro text and item image with link to the full article in the result page for Joomla Tags.

Is there a way to do this, or how can I modify the code to get the expected results?

I tried to add in components\com_tags\views\tag\tmpl\default_items.php `<?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>` but it does not work there as in other cases. I do not know php well enough, so would like to know if there are other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla functionality and would be better off on the [Joomla Q&A StackEchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1. Don't modify core files, Joomla has overrides, you lock yourself out of security updates by doing that.
2. What version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Updated

Use `<?php echo $item->core_body; ?>`  because the tags results use the standardized field names.

However the standard view of tagged items (non compact) contains an option that allows you to display the text (it will be intro text for an article, description for a weblink, category or news feed, or street address for a contact).  You need to select this when making a menu item for that tag. Or  got to global settings and change `Item description` to show or make a layout that does not use the show/hide parameter or defaults to show.

This is the relevant code block:

```
    <?php if ($this->params->get('', 1)) : ?>
        <?php echo $item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
        <span class="tag-body">
            <?php echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $item->core_body, $this->params->get('tag_list_item_maximum_characters')); ?>tag_list_show_item_description
        </span>
        <?php echo $item->event->afterDisplayContent; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Notice that tag_list_show_item_description  can be turned on or off.

Comment: I used it but it gives me no result, nothing at all appears, only the title.

Comment: Did you dump out $this->item? Are you sure that is the right thing to be echoing? I just copied from you and didn't look at the source. I think it should probably be $item but you need to look at the layout code.

Comment: I tried dump and got tag names, category names and a thousands of parameters as a result, then I tried to dump out the `$this->item->core_body;` and got NULL. Are there any ideas?

Comment: What is the title field called?

Comment: You don't have this line? `<?php echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $item->core_body, $this->params->get('tag_list_item_maximum_characters')); ?>`

Comment: I have this line, but what it has to do with article intro text? Nothing brings me back the intro text. I tried almost everything, I consider the solution is some more difficult than we think. Tag component does not behave like content component or something like this)). However, thanks. If there are other suggestions, please, post them.

Comment: Core_body is the intro text.  WHen you make the menu link and ask it to show the text does't it show? You should not need to do an override since the option is built into the view.